# Export manually missed globals object with future

Tags: r, future

I defined a function `f` in a package that takes data and an R expression as input and then applies the user-defined expression on the data. Here's an example of the function's use:

```
f <- function(data, expr) {
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  eval(expr, envir = data)
}

data <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4)
f(data, mean(a))
#> [1] 1.5
```

The problem arises with the parallel version of this function using explicit futures and user-defined object. Here a toy version:

```
library(future)

f <- function(data, expr) {
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  y <- future::future(eval(expr, envir = data))
  future::value(y)
}

data  <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4)
myfun <- function(x){sum(sqrt(x))}

plan(sequential)
f(data, myfun(a))
#> [1] 2.414214

plan(multiprocess)
f(data, myfun(a))
#> Error in myfun(a) : impossible to find function "myfun"
```

The problem is that `myfun` cannot trivially be found by `future` and thus must be exported manually. I'm able to fix this issue by analyzing `expr` with `future::getGlobalsAndPackages` and then manually adding objects:

```
future::future(..., globals = structure(TRUE, add = globals))
```

I'm wondering if there is a better/good way to do that since it looks like a hack to me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that the ellipsis in `plan` propagates to `future`

```
 plan(multiprocess, globals = myfun)
```